# Error for the version of google services

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Even after updating the version same error continues to pop up whenever the gradle is built.

**Project base gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
   }
```

**App base gradle **

```
ependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and the error is shown as follows:-

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: error is self explanatory did you read at least read it? now check ever single dependency versions

Comment: @Qwerty
 have you Fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Your all firebase version should be same.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.0'
```

update it

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```